# How `Material` property is attached to ApplicationWindow?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I would like to implement exactly the same but with my attached to ApplicationWindows property:

```
ApplicationWindow {
/*...*/
    Material.theme: Material.Light
    Material.accent: Material.Green
    Material.primary: Material.LightGreen
/*...*/
    MySingleton.prop1: 123
    MySingleton.prop2: "abc"
}
```

My thoughts were:

1. `qmlRegisterSingletonType<MySingleton>("U.R.I", 0, 1, "MySingleton", MySingletonFactory);`
2. `qml_engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("MySingleton", &MySingletonInstance);`

... but no luck: qrc:​/TestApp.​qml:​25 Non-​existent attached object

However, If I'm trying to access the same property in onCompleted callback:

```
ApplicationWindow {
/*...*/
    Component.onCompleted: {
        //console.log("Attached property1: ", MySingleton.prop1);
    }
/*...*/
}
```

... property is accessible.

How this can be achieved? What am I missing or misunderstanding?
Thank you!

Comment: It is exactly how you say it, attached. But probably you didn't catch the fact that you can implement Attached properties in QML. Read this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers

Comment: @Amfasis Thanks! You mean that Material properties under the hood are defined in QML(e.g. `property color accent`) and therefore can be modified in that way? So the general difference that my Singleton is attached(I would say 'injected') to the QML context from cpp code and there is no way to set its property value(f.e. prop1) in the same manner as Material's ones.

Comment: No, the Material properties are written in C++ and by using implementing `static <AttachedPropertiesType> *qmlAttachedProperties(QObject *object);`, the Qml engine knows that an attached property is available. Maybe this doc is more helpfull actually: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#providing-attached-properties

Comment: @Amfasis, Thank you again, I will take a look.